# Yocto, Petalinux 2017.1, SIGGEN_LOCKED_SIGS_T

Tags: embedded-linux, xilinx, yocto, openembedded, petalinux

I think this is a more specific Yocto problem so therefore I'm trying Stack Overflow:

During my Petalinux 2017.1 build I get the following warnings for a few packages, all of them in the recipes-core:

```
The init-ifupdown:do_unpack sig is computed to be cad131d20f065f81a9524376bd7d40bc, but the sig is locked to f2c445306ecd0f9936cc1b9d35a0587e in SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_t-cortexa9hf-neon
```

These scripts are mostly used to substitute config files like /etc/network/interfaces and such. It seems these config files are not changed, so I was wondering if this warning is related.

I did not have this problem in Petalinux 2016.4, so the recipes has been given a run through before.

Comment: Try to see differences in `/poky/meta/lib/oe/sstatesig.py` maybe something changed between versions. Did you change the script that has the problem? If yes, Did you recalculate checksum for those files?

Comment: @LPs There were minor changes to `sstatesig.py`, mainly python tweaks. I did not recalculate the checksum for those files - and I think that is the solution. What is the best way to do this? I have tried now avoiding with `BB_STRICT_CHECKSUM = "0" ` and also `SRC_URI[md5sum] = "???" ` but no success yet.

Comment: I'm not use dto modify recipe. You shold use your own layer to do so. BTW you should try to modify the recipe using the proposed CHSUM. In your example is `cad131d20f065f81a9524376bd7d40bc`

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this warning, add the following line in plnx_proj/project-spec/meta-user/conf/petlinuxbsp.conf:

```
SIGGEN_UNLOCKED_RECIPES += "init-ifupdown"
```